# Why is my purge command messing up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js-commando to create a purge command, but whenever I try to purge something that has double digits, it doesn't purge the number of messages I want. Example, I tell the bot to purge 99 messages, and it only purges 9.
Code:

```
const Commando = require("discord.js-commando");

class PurgeCommand extends Commando.Command {
    constructor(Client) {
        super(Client, {
            name: "purge",
            group: "moderation",
            memberName: "purge",
            description: "Deletes a specified amount of messages.",
            examples: ["purge [Number of Messages (MAX LIMIT: 100) ]"]
        })
    }

    async run(message, args) {
        if (message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
            if (!isNaN(args[0]) && parseInt(args[0]) > 0) {
                if (parseInt(args[0]) > 99) {
                    async function Purge() {
                        message.delete();
                        const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: 99});
                        message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched);
                        message.reply("I've successfully purged **" + fetched.size + "** messages.");
                    }

                    Purge();
                } else {
                    async function aPurge() {
                        message.delete();
                        const afetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: parseInt(args[0])});
                        message.channel.bulkDelete(afetched);
                        message.reply("I've successfully purged **" + afetched.size + "** messages.");
                    }

                    aPurge();
                }
            } else {
                message.reply("you have not specified a valid amount of messages to delete.")
            }
        } else {
            message.reply("you do not have permission to execute this command.")
        }
    }
}

module.exports = PurgeCommand;
```

`

Comment: Did you tried to see what does `args[0]` looks like?

Comment: I’ll try doing that

Comment: Did you find what was the problem?

Comment: Yea, args[0] gave me the first char instead of the entire word.

Comment: If you fixed it please post & accept your answer, so that this question doesn't display as unanswered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. `args[0]` gave me the first char of the argument instead of the entire argument, so I just had to manually split the message’s content then get the first parameter that way.